# Reputation history display is broken in multiple ways

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-history

My [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo?tab=reputation) on SO (and other sites) is completely broken:

1. I can't open, or close, the expanding rows - clicking on the arrows does nothing here:

   [image]
2. When I switch pages (I.e. go to page two, or three, or back to one, or anything), I lose all the disclosure arrows:

   [image]

It seems to work for me on Meta, but I've heard reports of it being broken for others even on Meta.

Safari 9.0.1 on OS X 10.11.1. Note that I can't reproduce the arrows disappearing on Chrome.

Comment: Can confirm this is *not* the case on [hardwarerecs.se], [so], and [meta.se], in Chrome Canary 49.0.2570.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: I can't close the items that are already open/expanded on page load. Rest works. On this site it is broken as described. I'm on good old IE11/Win7

Comment: For me, the rep tab functions good except the recent three days, which can't be collapsed. Safari 9.0.1 with OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console, on page load or when trying to change something?

Comment: @chirlu No errors at all, which makes this even stranger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No repro on the arrows disappearing, but I pushed a fix for being unable to collapse rows that were already expanded when the tab loaded.

Will be live in the next build (2015.11.23.3914 on MSE/MSO, 2015.11.23.3019 elsewhere.)

Comment: Just tested, I can only repro the arrow disappearing thing in Safari - it works fine in Chrome latest.

Comment: @Undo Well, then I have an easy solution for you... ;)

Comment: @Undo On a more serious note, I asked Kurtis to try it out in Safari and he can't repro either. I'll check when I'm home (where my mac is), but it sounds like something's possibly busted on your/Safari's end.