# Reputation breakdown not available on Meta.SE, but only if logged in

Tags: support, profile-page, reputation-history

When logged in and viewing *my own profile only*, and *only on Meta.SE* (so far), the reputation tab is aggregating all reputation earned from a post as if it were a single event.  Note (a) the absence of the expander and (b) that it uses the singular, e.g. "+30 upvote" rather than "3 events":

[image: screen shot]

I first noticed this two days ago, but it's apparently not the transient glitch I thought it might be then.

I've seen this in Firefox/Mac, Firefox/Windows, and Chrome/Mac (all browsers up to date and not dev/beta versions).  If I use an incognito/private window in Firefox or Chrome I don't see the problem -- and if I then log in, the problem occurs.

Other sites I checked (and are working as expected): Mi Yodeya, Workplace, Writers, Community Building, EL&U, Worldbuilding.

This might be related to  [Reputation history display is broken in multiple ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269810/reputation-history-is-broken-in-multiple-ways), but since the symptoms are different I'm reporting it separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently my view there had somehow gotten set to "time" rather than the default of "post".  I don't remember touching that (or even noticing it existed), and now that I've seen the "time" view I'm mystified by what signal it's meant to provide, but clicking on the "post" sort fixed my problem.